# Сортировка значений массива по значениям другого массива

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть два массива:

```
$val = array(
0=>21,
1=>23,
2=>12,
3=>45,
4=>6
);
$val2 = array(
0=>5,
1=>1,
2=>4,
3=>3,
4=>2
);
```

Мне нужно отсортировать первый массив по значениям второго.
В итоге должно быть так:

```
$val = array(
0=>23,
1=>6,
2=>45,
3=>12,
4=>21,
);
```

Есть идеи как так сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$val = array(0=>21, 1=>23, 2=>12, 3=>45, 4=>6);
$val2 = array(0=>5, 1=>1, 2=>4, 3=>3, 4=>2);
$val3 = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($val); $i++)
{
  $val3[$val2[$i] - 1] = $val[$i];
}
ksort($val3); // Сортируем по ключам
var_dump($val3);
```

Результат:

```
array(5) { [0]=> int(23) [1]=> int(6) [2]=> int(45) [3]=> int(12) [4]=> int(21) }
```

Comment: СПАСИБО!!! всё работает)

Comment: Только зачем цикл городить? `$val3 = array_combine($val2, $val1);`

Comment: Не знал на счет этой функции